# Taking an array from a multidimensional array and passing the values to variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This code is supposed to created a multidimensional array, `shuffle` it, select the first array, and pass the four values to four different variables called $`common`, `$uncommon`, `$rare`, and `$superrare`.

```
<?php

//create multidimentional array
$distribution = array
(
array(115, 50, 15, 0),
array(115, 49, 16, 0),
array(115, 48, 17, 0),
array(116, 49, 15, 0),
array(116, 48, 16, 0),
array(116, 47, 17, 0),
array(117, 48, 15, 0),
array(117, 47, 16, 0),
array(117, 46, 17, 0),
array(118, 47, 15, 0),
array(118, 46, 16, 0),
array(118, 45, 17, 0),
array(119, 46, 15, 0),
array(119, 45, 16, 0),
array(119, 44, 17, 0),
array(120, 45, 15, 0),
array(120, 44, 16, 0),
array(120, 43, 17, 0),
);

//shuffle the md-array
shuffle($distribution);

//select first array from $distribution
$slice[] = array_slice($distribution ,0, 1);

//create an array for key values
$cardrarity = array('common', 'uncommon', 'rare', 'superrare');

//combine $cardrarity and $slice
$cardraritycount = array_combine($cardrarity, $slice);

//create a variable for each value in 
foreach ($cardraritycount as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
    }
?>
```

When I view the contents of `$slice` it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 120
                    [1] => 43
                    [2] => 17
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

When I try and combine `$slice` with `$cardrarity`, I get no output when I try and echo the contents.  I think my problem is when I'm doing the array slice.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this a typo with 2 `$` here: `$$key = $value;`?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: No they are attempting variables variables.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, wow thanks! just found [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and I had no idea of such a thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_slice($distribution, 0, 1)` returns a multi-dimensional array. It's a 1-element array whose first element is the first element of `$distribution`. If you just want the first element of `$distribution`, use `$distribution[0]`.

To assign to multiple variables from an array, use an assignment to the `list()` function.

So the whole thing should be:

```
list($common, $uncommon, $rare, $superrare) = $distribution[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Rajdeep must have been a split second faster in answering.

Comment: But he didn't explain what was wrong with your code like I did.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to complicate such simple things. Simply do this:

```
// Shuffle the array
shuffle($distribution);

// Assign values to the respective variables
list($common, $uncommon, $rare, $superrare) = $distribution[0];

// Display values
echo $common . "<br />";
echo $uncommon . "<br />";
echo $rare . "<br />";
echo $superrare . "<br />";
```

Here's the reference:

- [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: That did it.  Thank you so much.  I'm just teaching myself PHP, wasn't aware of list.  Struggled with this one all day.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is `array_slice()` returning a multi-dimensional array but you are creating even another dimension with `$slice[]`.

Using `$distribution[0]` you have two options other than `list()`:

```
shuffle($distribution);
$cardrarity = array('common', 'uncommon', 'rare', 'superrare');
$cardraritycount = array_combine($cardrarity, $distribution[0]);
```

Then your `foreach()` works correctly:

```
foreach ($cardraritycount as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Or `extract()` the array as variables:

```
extract($cardraritycount);
```